# Deserializtion a JSON array string into a string array

Tags: c, arrays, deserialization

I am working with JSON strings for the first time and I have a Monday deadline so I don't have time to get into the nitty gritty of JSON.

I get this returned from the API:

```
["10","11","12","13","14","15","112","113"]
```

I need to convert it to some thing like:

```
string[0] = 10;
string[1]=  11;
```

etc...
 Can I convert that string into array?

I keep getting a deserializtion error because it cannot convert it from an array

Comment: `sprintf` may be able to help

Comment: @sukhvir You meant `sscanf`?

Comment: @user694733 Yes my bad .. i meant sscanf

Comment: http://www.json.org has a long list of JSON parsers for all languages including C.

Comment: *"I keep getting a deserializtion error"* - Where is your code, and what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(yourJSONresponse);

List list = new ArrayList();

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

list.add(arr.getJSONObject("name"));
}